# Error authoritatively enabling Project media-244309 Services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

When I execute the command terraform apply it throws the Error. Every configurations and connectivity from my local machine works fine. I checked using the below command.

1. gcloud auth login and
2. Verified using gcloud config list.

I have attached the main and variable tf files below

```
resource "google_project" "my_project" {
  name = "${var.project_name}"
  project_id = "${var.project_id}"
}

provider "google" {
  project = "${var.project_id}"
  region  = "${var.region}"
  zone    = "${var.zone}"
}

resource "google_project_services" "project" {
  project = "${var.project_id}"
  services   = ["composer.googleapis.com", "iam.googleapis.com", "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com"]
}

resource "google_pubsub_topic" "topic" {
  name    = "${var.topic}"
  project = "${var.project_id}"
}

resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "push_subscriptions" {
  count                = "${length(var.push_subscriptions)}"
  name                 = "${lookup(var.push_subscriptions[count.index], "name")}"
  topic                = "${google_pubsub_topic.topic.name}"
  project              = "${var.project_id}"

  depends_on = ["google_pubsub_topic.topic"]
}

resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "pull_subscriptions" {
  count                = "${length(var.pull_subscriptions)}"
  name                 = "${lookup(var.pull_subscriptions[count.index], "name")}"
  topic                = "${google_pubsub_topic.topic.name}"
  project              = "${var.project_id}"

  depends_on = ["google_pubsub_topic.topic"]
}
```

Variables.tf file

```
variable "project_id" {
  default     = "media-intelligence-244309"
}

variable "region" {
  default     = "asia-south1"
}

variable "zone" {
  default     = "asia-south1-b"
}

variable "project_name" {
  default     = "media-intelligence"
}

variable "topic" {
  default     = "topic-1"
}

variable "push_subscriptions" {
  type        = "list"
  default     = []
}

variable "pull_subscriptions" {
  type        = "list"
  default     = []
}
```

Error: Error applying plan:

3 error(s) occurred:

- google_project_services.project: 1 error(s) occurred:
- google_project_services.project: Error authoritatively enabling Project media-244309 Services: Get https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/media-244309?alt=json&prettyPrint=false: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request
  Response: {
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Robot is disabled."
  }

Comment: Do you have a billing problem?

Comment: Make sure 
 the proper setting: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/getting_started.html#adding-credentials